# Programmatically cause onBlur to trigger in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I use onBlur to close a dropdown, but I also want to handle a click handler of an li which is render within, setState won't work here, the behavior is broken when user try to open the dropdown again, try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ur1rbcrz

My code:

```
toggleDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({
        openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div tabIndex="0" onFocus={this.toggleDropdown} onBlur={this.toggleDropdown}>
          MyList
        <ul className={this.state.openDropdown ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
          <li>abc</li>
          <li>123</li>
          <li onClick={()=> this.setState({openDropdown:false})}>xyz</li> {/* not working */}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not working because, even though you `click` `li`, a `div` container with `onBlur` event still is focused.

We add to your list container `ref`, after that we can call `.blur()`. We use it in your `onClick` `li` event handler.

```
this.dropDownList.blur()
```

See working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur1rbcrz/5/).

Or run this snippet:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isDropdownVisible: false
    }
    
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleDropdown() {
   this.setState({
     isDropdownVisible: !this.state.isDropdownVisible
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div 
        tabIndex="0" 
        ref={c => this.dropDownList = c}
        onFocus={this.toggleDropdown} 
        onBlur={this.toggleDropdown}>
          MyList
        <ul
        className={this.state.isDropdownVisible ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
          <li>abc</li>
          <li>123</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.dropDownList.blur()}>xyz</li> {/* not working */}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello initialName="World"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}

div:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

div:focus {
  outline: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I use toggle instead of hide and show handler is to avoid 2 function.

Comment: @CeldricKang it is easier to debug this way and maintain your code.The code works I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @CeldricKang let me update, so we can have `toggle` instead `show`, `hide`.

Comment: @CeldricKang Ok, I've updated my answer. If it is ok to you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

i added onClick event to your div and it worked, your code becomes:

```
  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div tabIndex="0" onClick={() => this.setState({openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown})} onFocus={this.toggleDropdown} onBlur={this.toggleDropdown}>
      MyList
    <ul className={this.state.openDropdown ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li onClick={()=> this.setState({openDropdown:false})}>xyz</li> {/* not working */}
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OnBlur is a React Synthetic event and can be used in two ways:

1. To trigger something:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [field, setField] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>Uppercase on blur</p>
      <input type="text" 
      value={field} 
      onChange={e=>setField(e.target.value)}
      //LOOK HERE !
      onBlur={e=>setField(e.target.value.toUpperCase())}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="OnBlur triggering:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

2. Be triggered by something

```js
const {
  useState,
} = React;

const Example = ({
  title
}) => {
  const [field, setField] = useState("");

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    p > {
      title
    } < /p> <
    p > Remove focus by pressing enter < /p> <
    input type = "text"
    value = {
      field
    }
    onChange = {
      e => setField(e.target.value)
    }
    //LOOK HERE !
    onBlur = {
      e => setField(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    }
    onKeyPress = {
      e => (e.key === 'Enter' ? setField(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) || e.target.blur() : null)
    }
    /> < /
    div >
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Example title = "OnBlur triggered:" / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

So to programmatically cause onBlur to trigger in react is necessary add an event to watch your change.

More info:
[React SyntheticEvents](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)